# app staging using maven

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, appengine-maven-plugin

I am building my war folder using

```
mvn clean install
```

And I am deploying the project using :

```
gcloud preview app deploy /{PATH}/appengine-staging/app.yaml  /{PATH}/appengine-staging/index.yaml /{PATH}/appengine-staging/cron.yaml --version=version-7 --project=project1-test
```

The previous two steps requires the Staging yaml files using

```
appengine-java-sdk/bin/appcfg.sh stage <WAR-dir> <yaml-dir>
```

is there any way to do the staging step (without deploying ) using maven ?

Comment: mvn gcloud:stage , this what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the recently released `appengine-maven-plugin`. You probably wish to use:

```
mvn clean package appengine:stage
```

- Standard [(Using)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/using-maven) [(Reference)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven-reference)
- Flexible [(Using)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-maven) [(Reference)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/maven-reference)